# Is there a Latin source for "He who is able to laugh at himself, is invincible"?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, reference-request

Some time ago I came across a Latin sentence that roughly came down to:

> "*He who is able to laugh at himself, is invincible*"

At the time I thought: Oh well, this must be a well known Roman saying (easy to find later). Unfortunately, I can't seem to find it any more… Hence why I came here.

I've searched G.J.M. Bartelink's *Latin citations and sayings* (Dutch: *Latijnse citaten en gezegden*), but could not find anything in this direction.

Is anyone familiar with this phrase in Latin? If so, what is the earliest source? If not, would someone mind providing a (classical) Latin translation of it.

Comment: It is a very interesting question, but from what I am able to relate in the Roman psyche, self-humiliation was hardly considered a virtue. To the Roman, such an idea would be anywhere from ridiculous to insane. I would be extremely surprised if the source was classical. There is a [deep monograph](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-90-481-9661-6) on the topic:of the history of humiliation, but I cannot remember it even touching the self-ridicule being a thing even worth mentioning. To the Roman, a maxim “He who laughs at himself, is mentally unstable” would be more apt.

Comment: Another thought, try combing through Plautus and Terentius. Someone who is deluded that he'd be invincible because of his humility or self-ridicule would make a perfect laughing stock for the comedy.

Answer (score 7):

I can't find the exact phrase but perhaps the following capture the spirit of it.

> *nemo risum praebuit qui ex se cepit*
>
> no one becomes a laughing-stock who laughs at himself

Seneca, *De Constantia*, 17.3 - this is the translation of J. W. Basore (1928); my own (clunky) translation is: no one provided [themselves] as an object of laughter who seized it to their own advantage.

> *eum gaudere, qui ridet*
>
> he who laughs has joy

Seneca, *Epistles*, 23.3 – bearing in mind that joy for Seneca is a very serious business (*verum gaudium res severa est*) because true joy will help you face life’s ups and downs, even death, with equanimity.

Comment: A very good answer. I wonder whether qui ex se cepit could mean "who began with himself", in effect for initium cepit.

Comment: As in :  “ea pars artis, ex quā capere initium solent,” Quint. 2, 11, 1. (ap. L/S).

Comment: @fdb I hadn't thought of that but it works well and has the added advantage of being a less tortured translation than mine, which surely counts in its favour!

Answer (score 4):

I don't recall seeing that saying anywhere, but here is a translation suggestion:

> *Insuperabilis est qui se ridere potest.*

One might expect *ridere sibi* instead of *ridere se*, but *ridere* appears to work with the accusative rather than the dative.
Other possible translations of "invincible" would be *invictus* and *invincibilis*, but I like *insuperabilis* better.

With a tweaked word order this becomes a pentameter verse:

> *Qui ridere potest se insuperabilis est.*

The closest thing I could find with corpus searches is from Seneca's *Epistulae Morales ad Lucilium* 78: *Non vincetur dolor ratione, qui victus est risu?*
Perhaps I was trying the wrong words, but it seemed hard to find anything related to laughing and victory close to each other.

Comment: I'm surprised about the accusative. My first thought was it needed a proposition like _a_ or _de_

Comment: Ha! Thanks for the pentameter! It has a nice ring to it.

Comment: Since I forgot to write down the source (which I regret in hindsight), I can only rely on fallible memory. I believe it was a cut-out of a quite long sentence. This clue probably does not help very much at all. I know.

Comment: @Rafael So am I, but after looking at the examples in Lewis and Short, it seems that accusative is the way to go. My intuition says otherwise, but I'll trust L&S more than myself on this.

Comment: @Jim If you happen to know any of the key words in that sentence, that would help. I did a corpus search with some combinations of laughing and winning and I didn't find much. (I put one finding in the answer.)

Answer (score 2):

The Glasgow University collection of [emblem books](https://www.emblems.arts.gla.ac.uk/alciato/emblem.php?id=A15a150) (with their translations) is an accessible source for mottos and adages. This one refers to Heraclitus, the weeping philosopher, and Democritus, the laughing philosopher. The closest I came to the adage you remember comes in lines 3 and 4.

> Plus solito humanae nunc defle incommoda vitae
>   Heraclite: scatet pluribus illa malis.
>   **Tu rursus, si quando aliàs, extolle cachinum,
>
>   Democrite: illa magis ludicra facta fuit.**
>   Interea haec cernens meditor, qua denique tecum
>   Fine fleam, aut tecum quo modo splene iocer.
>   ( https://www.emblems.arts.gla.ac.uk/alciato/facsimile.php?id=sm1225_yy5v  )

If that's not what you had in mind, here are two leads:

[Juvenal, Satires](http://www.tertullian.org/fathers/juvenal_satires_10.htm) 10, 28ff  (Satire 10 paragraph 3)

> Then will you not commend the two wise men, one of whom [[4. 
>   Democritus of Abdera.]]  would laugh while the opposite sage [[5. 
>   Heraclitus of Ephesus]] would weep every time he set a foot outside
>   the door? To condemn by a cutting laugh comes readily to us all; the
>   wonder is how the other sage's eyes were supplied with all that water.
>   The sides of Democritus shook with unceasing laughter...

Juvenal's Sources are discussed in:
**Juvenal's Tenth Satire** (Paul Murgatroyd)
(Sources p.17 Note 19)

> .**19**. Juvenal's knowledge of Democritus may have come (at least in part)
>   from Seneca.  In his *Tranq. Animi* (at 2.3), Seneca translated
>   Democritus *euthymia* as *tranquilitas.* ...and at 15.2 he made the
>   contrast between laughing Democritus and the weeping Heraclitus and
>   advised imitating the former (cf Juv. 10: 28ff.).